# how to show JSON data dynamically on a single swift UI using "previous" and "next" buttons?

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode12

This is the user interface of my app:

[image: here is app ui]

I am still a learner. I can’t find the logic for my code (for the action of "previous" and "next" buttons). When the user clicks the "next" or "previous" button, I would like to change the song’s number, title and body dynamically.

How can I code that?

This is my code:

```
//  SongDetail.swift
import SwiftUI

struct SongDetail: View {
   var song: Song
   var body: some View {
       ScrollView {
            HStack {
                      Button(action: {
                           // <- goto previous item
                           }) {
                               Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                               Text("Previous")
                           }.disabled(song.SongId <= 0) // <- should stop going out of range
                           Spacer()
                           Button(action: {
                                // <- goto Next item
                           }) {
                               Text("Next")
                               Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                           }.disabled(song.SongId >= songs.count) // <- should stop going out of range
                       }
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(song.SongNo )
                 Text(song.SongTitle)
                    .font(.title2)
                 Text(song.SongBody)
            }
            .padding()
        }
        
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}

struct SongDetail_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SongDetail(song: songs[0])
    }
}
```

---

```
struct Song: Codable, Hashable{
   var SongId: Int
    var SongNo: String
    var SongTitle: String
    var SongBody: String
  }
```

Comment: You should have an array of Song, [Song], if you want to do next/previous. Where is your collection of songs?

Answer (score 0):

Add songs list array in SondDetails struct and keep track of your index with currentIndex.

```
struct SongDetail: View {
    @State var currentIndex: Int = 0
    var songs: [Song] = [] //<--- Songs list array
    var song: Song {
        songs[currentIndex]
    }
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    // <- goto previous item
                    if currentIndex > 0 {
                        currentIndex -= 1
                    }
                    
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                    Text("Previous")
                }.disabled(song.SongId <= 0) // <- should stop going out of range
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    // <- goto Next item
                    if currentIndex < songs.count {
                        currentIndex += 1
                    }
                    
                }) {
                    Text("Next")
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                }.disabled(song.SongId >= songs.count) // <- should stop going out of range
            }
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(song.SongNo )
                Text(song.SongTitle)
                    .font(.title2)
                Text(song.SongBody)
            }
            .padding()
        }
        
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```